# Is google docs java api V3.0 stable?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I downloaded gdata 1.47 and tried the demo, it cannot work properly, even failed to upload a file into google doc. Also base64 image content in HTML file cannot be recognized.
Can someone have a look at these issue? Or provide me a working code sample for using V3.0 java api.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some samples:

[http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Fsample%2Fdocs](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/sample/docs)

Comment: yes, i have downloaded those, but still have a problem of uploading image file with google format.